# Strange error Return not working in some cases

Tags: python, return, binary-search

So I am having a weird issue with something that is suppose to be simple: 
return vs. print

I was practicing coding for a binary search

```
def binary_search(data, n):
if len(data) == 0:
    return False
x = (len(data))//2
if data[x] == n:
    #The following line seems to be the problem
    return x
elif n < data[x]:
    binary_search(data[:x], n)
else:
    binary_search(data[x+1:], n)]
z = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
print(binary_search(z, 9))
```

This returns None

If I switch from return x --> print(x)

```
# CODE CODE CODE      
print(x)
#CODE CODE CODE

print(binary_search(z, 9))
```

This returns

```
2
None
```

I know the Binary Search itself works (2 is the correct answer) and that 'None' comes from the two print statements but when there is just one print statement

```
 # CODE CODE CODE      
 return x
 #CODE CODE CODE
 print(binary_search(z, 9))
```

It just prints None

Any idea why this is happening? I don't want the method to automatically print unless I ask

Another strange thing is

```
 #ORIG CODE
 return False
 #ORIG CODE

 y = []
 print(binary_search(y, 9))
```

Returns

```
False
```

So in that case 'return' is acting like I expect it to

I even tried switching return x to return True, it still returns None

Comment: The last two branches of your code (`elif n < data[x]`, `else`) don't return anything.

Comment: @melpomene But isn't that fine since they call the function again and eventually the elif and else lead to something being returned?

Comment: Doesn't matter. There's no `return` statement, so they implicitly return `None`.

Comment: @melpomene Thank you! I switched it to: return binary_search(data[ :x], n) and that fixed it